# How to convert array to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array different objects

```
{
  prac:[{
         "name":"xxx",
         "id":"1"
        }],
  abc: [{
        "description":"this is test description",
         "status":"active"
       }]
  }
```

Here I want to convert **prac** array to object.

Comment: you can easily access the object like this `jsonObj.prac = obj.prac[0];`

Comment: It is already is an object, since arrays are objects. Or can you show exactly what kind of object your want to convert it into? Do you mean you want to extract the first object in the array?

Comment: *I have a array different objects* to be precise, what you have is an object, the property values of which are arrays, the elements of which are objects.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. Angular is not a language, it's a framework based on JS.

Answer (score 2):

You should take the first element of the array. That's it

```js
var obj = {
  prac: [{
    "name": "xxx",
    "id": "1"
  }],
  abc: [{
    "description": "this is test description",
    "status": "active"
  }]
};

obj.prac = obj.prac[0];

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Actually, we can't understand the question. It **could** be that by "converting the array into an object" she means to take the first object inside the array, but on the other hand she might mean to create an object that looks like `{"0": {...}}`. In such cases, it's better to clarify the OP's intent first.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
  prac:[{
         "name":"xxx",
         "id":"1"
        }],
  abc: [{
        "description":"this is test description",
         "status":"active"
       }]
  };
  
var arrObj = jsonObj.prac;  

function toObject(arr) {
  var newJson = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    newJson[i] = arr[i];
  return newJson;
}

console.log(toObject(arrObj));
```

Comment: If this is actually what she wants to do, it's a good-enough answer; if it's not, then it's not. Did you consider asking her to clarify? By the way, why are using the word "JSON" in your naming for plain old JS objects which have nothing to do with JSON?